# The effects of a 'buy wall' on the market?

Tags: exchanges, trading

I'm learning a lot about coin markets. Now i'm wondering

#### What are the effects of a buy wall? or a sell wall? Do they affect the market in any way?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an economics question more than anything.

Comment: Doesn't really explain it.

Comment: The two questions that I linked cover your question to a large extent. If you feel that they don't answer your question, please clarify which aspect of the topic is still in question in regard to the related questions.